# How to remove a jar file in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I had `add jar file:///root/XXX.jar` in hive. But now, it is old. I want to remove it. I delete it in libs and the jar still works. What should I do to remove it?

Answer (score 3):

Use `DELETE` command:

```
DELETE { FILE[S] | JAR[S] | ARCHIVE[S] } [<filepath1> <filepath2> ..]
```

See docs here: [HiveResources](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-HiveResources)

Comment: Going from the OP's post the command would be DELETE JAR file:///root/XXX.jar